# Apache2 virtualhost serving on unspecified domains

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, http

I'm trying to set up my amazonaws EC2 instance with a wordpress HTTP server (`blog.mysite.com`) through apache and a node/express HTTP server (`[www.]mysite.com`) both running on port 80. From what I've found in the apache documentation, I should be using a virtualhost for this. This didn't work, and instead served files for both `blog.mysite.com` and `[www.]mysite.com`. Here is my 000-default config for apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/websites/blog/html/ # wordpress directory
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are my dns rules from NameCheap's dns configuration.

```
mysite.com CNAME my-amazonaws-public-dns
www.mysite.com CNAME my-amazonaws-public-dns
blog.mysite.com CNAME my-amazonaws-public-dns
```

Thanks! Tell me if you need any clarification or command output.

Comment: Where's your _other_ virtual host?

Comment: I'm under the assumption that I can just use the one virtual host to redirect traffic going to the subdomain that it specifies. Is this wrong?

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid now. I didn't think about creating multiple virtual hosts, but when I made another one for www and / in conjunction with proxypass it worked perfectly. Thanks Michael!